# Badge for reaching daily cap on single answer / question

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

A cool and rare badge would be to get a badge for reaching the daily cap limit solely on a single answer and another badge for reaching your daily cap limit on a single question.

You can still gain rep from other answers but if your cap limit is already reached a hidden running rep count will continue. Should that hidden rep count for that specific answer / question be reached, you get the badge.

This would also take into account the +15 if your answer is accepted or +2 if you choose an answer for a question you asked.

I am not sure of what the badge would be named. Maybe some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not sure I see the value in such a badge. There's no specific behavior that this would encourage that the Nice Answer, Enlightened, Mortarboard, and other badges don't already encourage.

A new badge should really only be introduced if it helps improve the site by encouraging more positive behaviors. Adding a badge just to add a badge would just add more noise.

For example, when Stack Exchange added the new review queues, they added 3 new badges to encourage people to go check out the review queues. Value was added by creating these badges. But I'm not sure how awarding reputation caps on single questions would encourage more good question/answer writing behaviors than what the other badges have already done.

Comment: I thought it would encourage people to give great quality answers in hopes of getting a bunch of upvotes to reach their daily cap limit

Answer (score 4):

There is already a badge for 10 upvotes on an answer or a question, and there is a badge for reaching the rep cap.  So there is no need to get a badge for the combined action.

Comment: This does it in a single day. That badge that exists is for a lifetime plus 10 upvotes doesn't get you your cap limit